# How to load csv.gpg file from GCS to Bigquery suing airflow or python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, gnupg

we have a requirement to decrypt and load .gpg file from GCS to Bigquery in airflow. Is there any easiest quick way to decrypt and load at same time from gcs to BQ?

The process I have used :

1. download the file to local server
2. decrypt and upload the same to gcs
3. load from gcs to BQ

   ```
    import pgpy
    import os
    from google.cloud import secretmanager
    from google.cloud import storage
    from io import BytesIO

    def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, output, bucket_name):
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
        blob.upload_from_string(data=output.read())
        output.close()
        return blob.public_url

    def get_secret(project, key_id, version):

        client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
        name=f"projects/{project}/secrets/{key_id}/versions/{version}"
        response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})
        return response.payload.data.decode('ascii')

    fetch_key = get_secret('project', 'secret_key', version)
    key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_blob(fetch_key) 
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')

    blob = bucket.blob('test.csv.gpg')
    local_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'teest.csv.gpg')
    blob.download_to_filename(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test.csv.gpg'))
    print(local_path)
    msg_encrypted = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file(local_path)
    msg_plaintext = BytesIO((key.decrypt(msg_encrypted).message))
    print(msg_plaintext)
    g=upload_to_bucket('test.csv', msg_plaintext, 'buckeet')
    print(g)
   ```

   os.remove(local_path)

Do we have any option to read directly from gcs and load to BQ?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I do not know if it is faster to do it, but  you can decrypt and load a gpg file from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery using Cloud Functions and Cloud Run.

Comment: @FerreginaPelona I am thinking of following steps : 1. gcs to local download 2. using PGPy decrypt the file and store as .csv 3. .then using GCS to BQ operator load the file